# How to disable UIButton highlight action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to implement an analog of segmented control with two buttons. In default state they have no images, only labels, in selected one they have background image. I want to activate control with TouchDown event.

here is the code (I removed all unnecessary things):

```
-(IBAction) onButton1
{
    button1.selected = YES;
    button2.selected = NO;
}

-(IBAction) onButton2
{
    button1.selected = NO;
    button2.selected = YES;
}
```

the problem is: assume button1 is selected. When I touch button2 it does not change its image to "selected" image (there is no default image, as I've said), but when I release finger it changes. Also, if I touch already selected button it removes "selected" image and return it when I release it.

I've set highlighted state of buttons, so they have "selected" image in that state, but it did  not help (not only in IB, but also with `[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`). I've set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO, that did not help too, again, in both program way and IB.

I've seen a lot of similar (but not identical) questions here, but they did not work for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you wanted to activate the action at touch down event, I assume that you dont need highlighting. Try the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnsel.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1TouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    button1.selected = YES;

    button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(80.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnsel.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2TouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

    [self.view addSubview:button2];
}

- (void)button1Action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    button1.highlighted = NO;
    button1.selected = YES;
    button2.selected = NO;
}

- (void)button2Action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    button2.highlighted = NO;
    button2.selected = YES;
    button1.selected = NO;    
}

- (void)button1TouchUp:(id)sender
{
    button1.highlighted = NO;
}

- (void)button2TouchUp:(id)sender
{
    button2.highlighted = NO;
}
```

Comment: I am not only dont need highlight, it should not be here. Your code really disables it, except situation when you touch already selected image.. there should be the last step :) anyway, thanks

Comment: I really did not understand your comment. However, I am sharing the link of the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/3k4fyswhg7kyij4/Stack.zip. You can take a look. thanks.

Comment: sorry my english. I should really improve it and stop using russian language constructions in english :) I ended with setting highlighted = NO in TouchUp, TouchDown and TouchDrag event and all seems to work, so thanks for answer!